# Recover entire Windows 10 install from windows.old

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, windows.old

My PC recently ran into some issues and I had to end up reinstalling Windows to fix the boot (which is done). But I must've accidentally installed Windows again on the drive that I wanted to fix since there is a `windows.old` folder with all my programs, files, etc.

That was indeed a Windows 10 version inside the `windows.old` and I was wondering in there was a way I could recover or restore everything (all user profiles, settings, programs, files, and hopefully even the product key).

Answer (score 1):

According to answers.microsoft.com:

1. Start your PC as Windows attempts to load and the spinning dots appear, press and hold Power Button for 5 - 10 seconds. This is known as a Hard Shut Down
   (Do this twice )
2. Turn on your computer for the 3rd time and it should come up in the Recovery Environment
3. You will be prompted for System Repair/Safe Mode/Command Prompt
4. Go to Troubleshoot - Advanced Option - Revert to previous build of Windows
5. If this is unsuccessful, go to Troubleshoot - Advanced Options - Reset this PC
   Choose to keep your files and apps.

Another way to do it (without a reboot) using windows options AND a video step by step is [right here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8usuErtgPc).

Comment: When I select safe mode, it simply boots up windows in safe mode and while I can run command prompt, I'm not sure what to do with it and I can't find troubleshoot - advanced option

Comment: I added a link to a video that will walk you through it.

Comment: All I have on the recovery section of settings is "reset this pc" and "advanced startup".

Comment: Did you try "reset this pc" like my instructions above advise? (aka step 5)..

Comment: yes, I did try that method as well and I am not seeing that option

Comment: sorry man.. I don't know what to tell you at this point. :(

Comment: Thanks for helping out anyways! I really appreciated it